# Zip fails after PHP download

Tags: php, bash, unzip

I am creating a PHP service where a user can download external ZIP files from another server to the server with the PHP. After download I keep getting this ZIP error stating that the file was corrupt / multi-part. That's not the case. I can't extract it on the linux server but when I copy it over to my OSX machine it extracts flawlessly when I double click on the archive but the terminal `unzip` command gives the same error. I'm confused:

```
Archive:  pdbeUpload.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

Here's the link to the file (140MB):

```
ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/emdb/structures/EMD-2754/map/emd_2754.map.gz
```

Remember, my aim is to automate the download process, so I need to get to understand why this fails.

Here's what I'm getting with gunzip:

```
gunzip pdbeUpload.zip 
gzip: pdbeUpload.zip: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

And for `bunzip2`, to be complete:

```
bunzip2: pdbeUpload.zip is not a bzip2 file.
```

Comment: Maybe read up some on the differences of gzip and zip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094

Comment: no dude, why should I?

Comment: Because knowing things is cool.  Phil Katz RIP.

Comment: Can't stop banging my head against a wall due to folks that hang out on forums and don't provide constructive help. Obviously stackoverflow reputation must not correlate with human skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a gzip archive, not zip. Use `gunzip`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I will notify the file provider that they should rename their files to gz.

Comment: In the link, it is called `emd_2754.map.gz`. I can't tell you where it got renamed to `.zip`. You can unpack gzip files with a .zip extension with `gunzip -S .zip foo.zip`, but it'd be better to have the file with a correct filename extension. You could also use something like [atool](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/) that handles different archive formats.

Comment: Not sure what happened that it became a zip, I'll look into it further. Thanks for your input though.