# With node's api/zlib I'm getting errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'

Tags: node.js, zlib, compression

The sample data can be [found here allCountries.zip](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/allCountries.zip), it's the Postal Code database form geonames.org.

I'm running this code,

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const fs = require('fs');
const zip = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/allCountries.zip');

zlib.gunzip(zip, unzipData => console.log(unzipData) );
```

I'm getting this error,

```
{ Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:356:17) errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

I've also tried `zlib.unzip` which returns the same error, and `zlib.unzipSync` like this,

```
zlib.unzip(zip, unzipData => console.log(unzipData) );
```

which returns this stack dump,

```
zlib.js:536
      throw error;
      ^

Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:356:17)
    at Unzip.Zlib._processChunk (zlib.js:526:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/test.js:6:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:574:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:583:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:491:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:450:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:442:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:608:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7)
```

I'm using `v7.0.0-test2016100609987d242b`, but I've confirmed this is the same result with `v6.7.0`. This archive extracts properly with `gunzip -c` and `unzip`.

```
$ unzip -v ./allCountries.zip 
Archive:  ./allCountries.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
96309121  Defl:N 12668483  87% 2016-10-10 03:05 0666ed3f  allCountries.txt
--------          -------  ---                            -------
96309121         12668483  87%                            1 file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a zip file, not a gzip or zlib stream. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765054/1180620).) zlib does not handle zip files. You'll need to [find](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) or write code that parses the zip file format.