# How to install Objective C GZIP library for Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, gzip, carthage

I'm using Xcode 9.1 and Swift 3.2 for my current project.
I tried using 1024jp's GzipSwift library but I kept getting `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

So I decided to give the Objective C version a try.

Here's GZIP written in Objective C library https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP.

```
Alternatively you can use Carthage, or if you prefer to install manually, drag the GZIP.xcodeproj into your project or workspace and include GZIP.framework under the linked libraries in your target.
```

I couldn't figure out how to use Carthage nor drag the GZIP.xcodeproj (where exactly in the project should I drag it?) and I couldn't find the GZIP.framework file anyways.

I'm trying to avoid Cocoapods as much as possible bec it's proven to be troublesome in the past where I work.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following Apple documentation on how to embed frameworks:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html

You may also want to consider using Apple's Data Compression API, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/data_compression.  Among other algorithms it supports ZLIB, which is what GZIP uses, see [How are zlib, gzip and zip related? What do they have in common and how are they different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related-what-do-they-have-in-common-and-how-are-they).