# Compress into .zip file with node.js core zlib module

Tags: node.js, zlib, zip

How can I compress a file/files and save into a `.zip` extension file with the provided node.js [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) module? I figured how to save into `.gz` using gzip like the following:

```
const gzip = zlib.createGzip();
const fs = require('fs');
const input = fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt');
const out = fs.createWriteStream('myfile.txt.gz');

input.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
```

Comment: @Raptor: Gunzip, Gzip but they seems to be making tar.gz, not .zip. Also looked for linux commands and seems like there is a zip command. There are other modules available but I was hoping it must be possible with the provided zlib module, but couldn't find in google so far.

Comment: You mentioned about `node.js`, how do you want to use it with compressing file?

Comment: @Raptor: By openning a readfilestream and a writefilestream, piping the readstream through some function in zlib to the writefilestream? But what function do I use for .zip files?

Comment: So, where's your code ?

Comment: @Raptor: It's in here as an example of gzip: https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

Comment: Your question should relate to your implementation, instead of example codes from documentation.

Comment: @Raptor: Alright, I've edited the question with an implementation.

Comment: A `.zip` file can contain multiple files, and has directory information.  It seems that you would need an npm library that handles zip files (there are several) as it is doubtful a transform stream can handle more than one file in this way. A `.gz` file contains gzipped data of one file with no metadata about the file, so a transform stream could do those... but not .zip ...   Perhaps read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related-what-do-they-have-in-common-and-how-are-they especially the PKZIP spec he cites.

Comment: Try [jszip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/).