# Is it possible to zip data as we write the data in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stream, zip, zlib

I am able to append data to a file like this

row (this I will get )

```
 fs.appendFile('./file.txt', JSON.stringify(row) + '\n', (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
```

But how can I "append" the data while zipping it at the same time ? I am unsure if this is possible, If yes any pointers will be extremely helpful.
Can I achieve it through piping? if yes how?

```
zip.appendData('./file.zip',JSON.stringify(row) + '\n', (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        });
```

Something like above ?

Comment: Not sure it's possible, see this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638885/compress-into-zip-file-with-node-js-core-zlib-module#comment84276787_48638885). Are you restricted to `.zip` or can you use `.gz` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to append to a `.zip` archive without rewriting it.

If a `.gz` file is considered, you can use the built-in [`zlib`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gzip_buffer_options_callback) module to append directly to the `.gz` file.

```js
const zlib = require('zlib');

zlib.gzip(JSON.stringify(row), (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  fs.appendFile('file.txt.gz', data, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this gonna work, but maybe helps you.

You need `zlib` package on your project

```
npm install zlib
```

Code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

function WriteAndZip(filename) {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.appendFile(`./your_path/${filename}`, JSON.stringify(row) + '\n', (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        const fileContents = fs.createReadStream(`./your_path/${filename}`);
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`./your_path/${filename}.gz`);
        const zip = zlib.createGzip();
        fileContents.pipe(zip).pipe(writeStream).on('finish', (err) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            else resolve();
        });
    });
}
```