# Akka stream throws ParsingException when start decompressing .gz file from middle offset

Tags: scala, akka, gzip, akka-stream

I am reading **.gz** file from **AWS S3 bucket** using Akka streaming, The application reads chunk of data and process it.

The following code is working fine when I read file from beginning but if I start file from particular offset then Decompression fails and throws ParsingException.

**Code:**

```
object StreamApp extends App {

    // Run 1
    //startStreaming(0)
    // Run 2
    startStreaming(33339)

    def startStreaming(pointer: Long): Unit = {
        println("Stream App Starting")

        implicit val system = ActorSystem()
        val materializerSettings = ActorMaterializerSettings(system)
        implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(materializerSettings)
        implicit val dispatcher: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
        implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(1 seconds)
        
        val accessKey = "aws-access-key"
        val secretAccessKey = "aws-secret-access-key"

        val awsCredentials = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
            new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretAccessKey)
        )
        
        val s3Region: String = "s3-region-name"
        val s3Bucket: String = "s3-bucket-name"
        val s3DataFile: String = "s3-object-path.gz"
        
        val settings = new S3Settings(MemoryBufferType, None, awsCredentials, s3Region, false)

        val s3Client = new S3Client(settings)(system, materializer)

        val currentOffset: Long = pointer
        val source: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] =
            s3Client
                .download(s3Bucket, s3DataFile, ByteRange.fromOffset(currentOffset))

        val flowDecompress: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] =
            Flow[ByteString].via(
                Compression.gunzip()
            )

        val flowToString: Flow[ByteString, String, NotUsed] =
            Flow[ByteString].map(_.utf8String)

        val sink: Sink[String, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach(println)

        val (killSwitch, graph) =
            source
                .via(flowDecompress)
                .via(flowToString)
                .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
                .toMat(sink)(Keep.both)
                .run()

        graph.onComplete {
            case Success(_) =>
                println("Stream App >> File Data Extractor >> Stream completed successfully")
                killSwitch.shutdown()
        }
    }
}
```

The exception as follows:

```
[ERROR] [02/26/2018 12:13:10.682] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.dispatch.Dispatcher] Failure(akka.stream.impl.io.ByteStringParser$ParsingException: Parsing failed in step ReadHeaders) (of class scala.util.Failure)
scala.MatchError: Failure(akka.stream.impl.io.ByteStringParser$ParsingException: Parsing failed in step ReadHeaders) (of class scala.util.Failure)
    at StreamApp$$anonfun$startStreaming$1.apply(StreamApp.scala:71)
    at StreamApp$$anonfun$startStreaming$1.apply(StreamApp.scala:71)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:43)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I debug the code and following is my observation

Execution on this [line](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/coding/Gzip.scala#L81), the **readByte()** returns 3 and hence fails to understand the input is in .gz format

I am not able to decompress the .gz file's data chunk, I want guideline about this problem, if possible then please provide the pointers and correct me if I am wrong.

**Version:**

> Akka Version = "2.5.9"
>
> Akka Http Version = "10.0.11"
>
> Alpakka Version = "0.14"

Comment: Aren't gzip files meant to have headers which are placed at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Compression.scala#L35): `Compression.gunzip()` will create Flow that decompresses a gzip-compressed stream of data.

You can use the **file** utility on Linux or MacOS to see what algorithm was used to compress the file, in my case the file was compressed using zlib so `Compression.inflate()` did the trick.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related-what-do-they-have-in-common-and-how-are-they) for a good explanation on how zlib, zip and gzip are related.