# How to change deflate stream output format(raw, zlib, gzip) when use zlib?

Tags: gzip, zlib, deflate

`Zlib` can output [three format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related-what-do-they-have-in-common-and-how-are-they/20765054#20765054), I try to search the docs and `zlib.h`, but can't find a clear explanation about the options, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [zlib.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h#L566) documentation of `deflateInit2()`:

```
  windowBits can also be -8..-15 for raw deflate.  In this case, -windowBits
determines the window size.  deflate() will then generate raw deflate data
with no zlib header or trailer, and will not compute a check value.

  windowBits can also be greater than 15 for optional gzip encoding.  Add
16 to windowBits to write a simple gzip header and trailer around the
compressed data instead of a zlib wrapper.
```

Comment: Why use `windowBits ` to alter the wrapper file format. I really found this before, but     can't confirm that.

Comment: What is it that you can't confirm? It's written right there in the documentation.

Comment: here is an example of creation and decompression of raw DEFLATE stream https://github.com/stokito/deflate

Answer (score 1):

Fill in the blanks

```
int get_file_format(int n) {
  if      (n == 0) return 31;
  else if (n == 1) return 15;
  else if (n == 2) return -15;
  else if (n >= 9  && n <= 15) return n;  /* zlib with window size 2^9 to 2^15 */
  else if (n >= 25 && n <= 31) return n;  /* gzip with window size 2^9 to 2^15 */
  else if (n >= -15 && n <= -9)return n;  /* raw  with window size 2^9 to 2^15 */        
  else return Z_ERRNO;     
}

z_hist_sz = get_file_format(n);

ret = deflateInit2(&strm, COMPRESS_LEVEL, Z_DEFLATED, z_hist_sz ...)
```