# How to convert zip files to gzip in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
MyFile.zip
```

In Python, what is a neat way to convert the `.zip` file into a gzip file? e.g. final output `MyFile.gz`, a valid gzipped file.

Comment: Decompress and compress again. You might even need a tar layer if you have more than one file in the archive.

Comment: use the `gzip` module. Obviously you would need to decompress your `.zip` file first then compress into a `.gzip` file.

Comment: Extract the zip file and then gzip the file..

Answer (score 2):

There's a gzip module for this sort of conversion, I am going off the python docs for this, link [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gzip.html).

Basically what you're looking for is an input i.e. your current `file/path/to/zip/file` and then taking that as input to the gzip conversion by using `shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest)`. This is kinda like layman terms for how to do it but all the details are in the link.

Comment: I've just read https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765054/4130137 and realized it is not exactly so simple, since the .zip file is an archive and a .gz file is a compressed single file. I was hoping there would be a simple two-liner like doing a with gzip.open() and the zipfile equivalent and simply copying them across, but it'd probably be necessary to unzip the whole archive, and find the files I want to gzip, or tar the archive and then gzip.

Comment: or if it's that case then yes, a slightly longer approach may need to be taken