# I'm trying to convert this string into gzip

Tags: node.js, gzip, zlib

I'm using Node.JS and I'm trying to convert this string that looks like this

```
{"blocks":[{"id":"block","block":"event","args":{"items":[]},"action":"Join"},{"id":"block","block":"player_action","args":{"items":[{"item":{"id":"txt","data":{"name":"hi"}},"slot":0},{"item":{"id":"bl_tag","data":{"option":"Add spaces","tag":"Text Value Merging","action":"SendMessage","block":"player_action"}},"slot":25},{"item":{"id":"bl_tag","data":{"option":"Regular","tag":"Alignment Mode","action":"SendMessage","block":"player_action"}},"slot":26}]},"action":"SendMessage"}]}
```

into Gzip using zlib
I have tried following some answers on Stack Overflow like this

```
var deflated = zlib.deflateSync('{"blocks":[{"id":"block","block":"event","args":{"items":[]},"action":"Join"},{"id":"block","block":"player_action","args":{"items":[{"item":{"id":"txt","data":{"name":"hi"}},"slot":0},{"item":{"id":"bl_tag","data":{"option":"Add spaces","tag":"Text Value Merging","action":"SendMessage","block":"player_action"}},"slot":25},{"item":{"id":"bl_tag","data":{"option":"Regular","tag":"Alignment Mode","action":"SendMessage","block":"player_action"}},"slot":26}]},"action":"SendMessage"}]}').toString('base64');
var inflated = zlib.inflateSync(new Buffer(deflated, 'base64')).toString();

console.log(inflated);
```

But then I get the error:

```
{"blocks":[{"id":"block","block":"event","args":{"items":[]},"action":"Join"},{"id":"block","block":"player_action","args":{"items":[{"item":{"id":"txt","data":{"name":"hi"}},"slot":0},{"item":{"id":"bl_tag","data":{"option":"Add spaces","tag":"Text Value Merging","action":"SendMessage","block":"player_action"}},"slot":25},{"item":{"id":"bl_tag","data":{"option":"Regular","tag":"Alignment Mode","action":"SendMessage","block":"player_action"}},"slot":26}]},"action":"SendMessage"}]}
(node:25548) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve (this is after its been base64'd)
`H4sIAAAAAAAA/6VRsQrCMBD9lXKzgwg6ZHMVuqi4iJRrc8RgmpQmFaX03720RSviIE7JvXvv3rukhdy44uJBHFvQEsRQw2w8BdCVbOAaa8UsJgUqI/3UMVYE7SyTNk5b6GZfRlQG71RnI/tz1HDrkSgPt+gnMWCELJbE4FlDx47euABi3ltNNbnJAqqJzFVjtLWUia+wIM/dyBGwp1tIDmgaSlKqlbZR+NxlR1am5D0q+rrDK8pi+UOWLanGYP0MsjZa2ZLfN0mdpD9CrLq375iqufMAPTQAnOUBAAA=` (from a website)

Comment: I don't see an error, I only see a deprecation **warning**.

Comment: It dosent log the gzipped string though.

Comment: What is the line before the warning then? And note that you only write `inflated` to the console, not `deflated`.

Comment: This is not an error but a warning. And you can get around it by using `Buffer.from()`. And it doesn't log the gzipped result, because you are doing a `deflateSync` (ie compress) followed by an `inflateSync` (ie decompress) and only log the result of the decompression. You have to do `console.log(deflated)` to log out the zipped string

Comment: BTW your expected result does not seem to be Buffer originating from zlib compression because it throws an error on `inflateSync`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the *warning* against using `Buffer` ctor [which is documented as deprecated](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding) and as derpischer commented you can fix by using `Buffer.from`:

**TLDR: gzip != deflate** -- but abs(gzip-deflate)<epsilon

The zlib library, and the nodejs module accessing it, supports several formats that are similar and related but different and not the same, all using the deflate/inflate compression algorithm originally developed for (PK)ZIP, plus the newer Brotli algorithm (not relevant here).

zlib supports: (1) 'raw' inflate/deflate; (2) 'zlib' format, which adds a trivial header and an integrity check; (3) 'gzip' format, which adds a different header and a different integrity check. See [How are zlib, gzip and zip related? What do they have in common and how are they different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related#20765054) for an explanation of this situation by Mark Adler, one of the zlib authors.

nodejs confuses this slightly by using the names `{In,De}Flate` and `{in,de}flate[Sync]` for zlib format; `{In,De}FlateRaw` and `{in,de}flateRaw[Sync]` for raw format; and `G[un]zip` and `g[un]zip[Sync]` for gzip format. You are using the methods for zlib format, so you get zlib format and not gzip format; to get gzip format, use [the methods for gzip format](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gunzip_buffer_options_callback).