# How to open a gzip file in R?

Tags: r, gzip, zip

```r
unzip("fasta.gz")
```

> Warning message: In unzip("fasta.gz") : error 1 in extracting from zip file

I am trying to unzip a zip file but it is not working what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```r
# Input:
#   file_name: the name of the file to unzip
#
# Output:
#   file_name: the name of the unzipped file
#
# Usage:
#   file_name <- unzip_file(file_name)
#
unzip_file <- function(file_name) {
  file_name <- gzfile(file_name)
  file_name <- unzip(file_name)
  file_name <- gzfile(file_name)
  file_name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you are trying to decompress a *gzip* file, not a zip file. Those are two different things. `unzip` is for zip files. Use `gunzip()` or `gzfile()` for gzip files.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: They are two completely different file formats with different purposes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related-what-do-they-have-in-common-and-how-are-they