# What is the difference between 7-zip Deflate and zlib.compress()?

Tags: zlib, 7zip, deflate, lossless-compression

Helo everyone

I am trying to understand `Deflate` compression but from what i have seen i think i have misunderstood or done something wrong.
So i grabbed a source code for `7zip` so i might understand what is happening but the source code is hard to read and i couldn't find the function responsible for `Deflate` compression
but here is what's troubling me.

i have 2 text files.

Test1.txt has:

"*Helo everyone
I am trying to understand Deflate compression but from what i have seen i think i have misunderstood or done something wrong.
So i grabbed a source code for 7zip so i might understand what is happening but the source code is hard to read and i couldn't find the function responsible for Deflate compression
but here is what's troubling me.*"

Test2.txt has:

"*Helo everyone
I am trying to understand Deflate compression but from what i have seen i think i have misunderstood or done something wrong.
So i grabbed a source code for 7zip*"

if i use `zlib.compress()`

```
import zlib

def deflate_file(input_filename, output_filename):
    with open(input_filename, 'rb') as input_file:
        data = input_file.read()

    compressed_data = zlib.compress(data, zlib.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)

    with open(output_filename, 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(compressed_data)

input_file = 'test1.txt'
output_file = 'compressed.deflate'
deflate_file(input_file, output_file)
```

and i get this

```
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
```

but compressing the file with 7zip i get

```
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
```

Questions.

What is the difference between `zlib.compress()`  and **7zip**'s deflate?

How can i get same output as **7zip** from **zlib**?

Why are the outputs of 7zip's Deflate on test1.txt and test2.txt have different most significant bits as the input have?

If its possible i want to add a feature in my **7zip** source code to save the deflated data for analysis.

Comment: There is more than one compression algorithm, that produce different levels of compression. Some do a better job of compressing data, but take considerably longer to do so. Some do a lesser job of compression, but can do it very quickly. Find documentation for WinZip or 7zip, which explain the differences between the compression options they make available. Such an explanation is not a programming question according to this site's guidelines, so asking here is off-topic. You can, however, start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are compressing to two different formats. The `78 da` is the start of a zlib stream. The `50 4B` is the start of a zip file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765054/1180620

I do not believe that 7zip has an option to produce a zlib stream.

Comment: And why is it that test1 and test2 text files compressed by 7zip won't share the most significant bits like they do before compression?

Comment: Your question inexplicably provides a second test input, test2.txt, which then is never mentioned again in the question. I have no idea what your question is since you did not provide a question.