How to read gzip file download from an API
I`m trying to download a file from an API that give me sales of a client. But I dont know how to do it.
url = URI("https://conciliation.stone.com.br/v1/merchant/{MYCODE}/conciliation-file/20240909")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request["accept"] = 'application/xml'
request["Authorization"] = 'Bearer USERID'
request["X-Authorization-Raw-Data"] = 'ENCRIPTED STRING'
request["X-Authorization-Encrypted-Data"] = 'TOKEN'
request["Accept-Encoding"] = 'gzip'

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body

Ant that is whats it returns...
[3] pry(Stone)> response.read_body
=> "\x1F\x8B\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00}\x93\xCBn\x830\x10E\x7F\x05\xB1/\x06\xFA\b\x8D\x1CG\x15m\xDAJ]\xF4\x11u?\xC5\x93\xC4\xAA\xB1#l\xA2\xE4\xEFk\xC8\xA3@\b;k\xEE=3w\xC0\xA6\xD3m.\xBD\r\x16Fh5\xF1\xA3 \xF4=T\x99\xE6B-'~i\x17W\x89?e4\xD5*\x13R\x80u.\xCF\x11\xCA\x8C\xB7\x86O\xFC\x95\xB5\xEB1!&[a\x0E&0V+\f2\x9D\x13\x9F\xD1\x17\x04\x8E\x05\xA3\xCF\xA8\xB0\xA8\xC9G\xB08\x179\xB28\x8Co\xC2\xFB(\x8C\x92(\xBA\x8D)\xE9\xB1\xD0\xAF\xAAW\xAA9\xB2$\xBE\x8BF\xE1\xE8\xDA\x19\xFF\x8B\xF4\rv\xBA\xB4\xDF\xFB\xE4,\x0E\x9C\xDA.\xD1\x99\x90\xF8\xCAYH\xC9\xE1D?q\x81\x85[\x0F\xAB1\x87\x14aBI\xBBN\xC91\xFAL(p\x8B\x83\x9C\x17\xA0\fdUB\xE3\x91\x86\xF0\xB4Ae\xDB\xA5\xA6\xF7!\xCBt\xD95\xD4LSy\x87]~l\xE3h\x17\xD6\xCDNam\xCB\x02y\xB3\xDDG\t\xCA\n\xBB\xABv\x1A\xD4\x1D\xED\xB6\x91C\xF4\x80\xEE\x02\t\xFE\xAA\x8C\x05)\xEB`M\xF2\xA2F\xD3\x15\x14K\xE4\xFB\xD6\x12\xCEg\x0E\xE9\a\xFA\a\xB2\xDF\x1E\xA8]nz\xDD\xAF+\x15\xBF@t\xC4S\xC2\xA1Q\xBDj\xFDE\x06\xA7\x0E\ej~\x7FW\xBAP\xA7z\xCCxn\xEE\x17(9\xDD\x18\xD2|\xA5\xEC\x0F\xA7\x9FA\x1F\xDA\x03\x00\x00"

It should be a zip file, but I dont know how to read this.

I changed the code to...
if response['Content-Encoding'] == 'gzip'
  sio = StringIO.new(response.body)
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(sio)
  decompressed_body = gz.read
else
  decompressed_body = response.body
end

Seens to work fine. But i look for the file of many days, and always seens that doesnt have sales. But it has indeed

I tried that. but got error Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x8B" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 when tf.write(response.read_body)

Add what you tried to your question.

@dbugger I change to tf.write(response.read_body.force_encoding("UTF-8")) and seens to be good. it returns an integer. and tf looks like #<File:/var/folders/7q/ytrrfzr532n87tlywvwgvspm0000gn/T/temp20240910-61208-ojgij9.zip>. Now I need to use some Gem to read the zip?

Yes there are few gems to do that -- rubyzip

Your question's title and tags say "gzip" but you keep referring to "zip" and use .zip as the file extension. Those are different formats, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765054/477037. It's also not clear if you want to decode the API response in Ruby or if you want to save it to a file for further processing.

It's not zip, it's gzip. Two different things. Use the require 'zlib' library to decode it.
The example data decodes to:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Conciliation xmlns:xsd="http://schemas.stone.com/"><Header><GenerationDateTime>20240910181152</GenerationDateTime><StoneCode>826170732</StoneCode><LayoutVersion>2.2</LayoutVersion><FileId>0</FileId><ReferenceDate>20240908</ReferenceDate></Header><FinancialTransactions /><FinancialEvents /><FinancialTransactionsAccounts /><FinancialEventAccounts /><Payments /><Trailer><CapturedTransactionsQuantity>0</CapturedTransactionsQuantity><CanceledTransactionsQuantity>0</CanceledTransactionsQuantity><PaidInstallmentsQuantity>0</PaidInstallmentsQuantity><ChargedCancellationsQuantity>0</ChargedCancellationsQuantity><ChargebacksQuantity>0</ChargebacksQuantity><ChargebacksRefundQuantity>0</ChargebacksRefundQuantity><ChargedChargebacksQuantity>0</ChargedChargebacksQuantity><PaidChargebacksRefundQuantity>0</PaidChargebacksRefundQuantity><PaidEventsQuantity>0</PaidEventsQuantity><ChargedEventsQuantity>0</ChargedEventsQuantity></Trailer></Conciliation>


Is require 'zlib' needed / sufficient to make Net::HTTP return the decoded data automatically or does the OP still have to decode it?

i add this gem on my gemfile and it just crashed my application, cant explain whats happnd. i had to undo gemfile and gemfile.lock

@Stefan As I said, they need to "Use the library". A require statement by itself does nothing.

@DiogoAmaral the Zlib module belongs to Ruby's standard library and is part of Ruby's so-called default gems. You can require it directly without having to add it to your gemfile.

The server is not sending a zip file. It's just standard HTTP compression  with GZip and can be handled completely transparently by your HTTP client of choice.

Net::HTTP automatically adds Accept-Encoding for compression of response bodies and automatically decompresses gzip and deflate responses unless a Range header was sent.
Compression can be disabled through the Accept-Encoding: identity header.
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Compression

Of course of you don't want to deal with it send a different Accept-Encoding header to tell the server that you don't want the response compressed.

Sounds like response.read_body in the OP's example should already return the decoded value, what's missing?
